# How to display attributes and values for attribute type uniquely?

Tags: laravel

So i have an Attribute Model, which has a Many to Many relationship with the Products Model. So each product can have many attributes and vice versa.

**Attribute Table:**

[image]

**Product Table**
This is just simply product details price etc. Nothing fancy

**ProductAttribute Table** - Pivot table

[image]

In my controller i get the features of all the products like this. This is basically just getting the pivot table data:

````
$features = DB::table('product_attributes')
            ->distinct('attribute_id')
            ->whereIn('sku_product_id', $skuProductIDs)->get();```
````

Then in the view i have this code:

```
@foreach(\App\Models\Attribute::all() as $attribute)

    <div class="my-3">
        <label class="font-hk text-secondary mb-2">{{ $attribute->name }}</label>
            <div class="my-1">
                @foreach($features as $feature)

                    @if($feature->attribute_id === $attribute->id)
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox h-5 w-5 text-gray-600 feature-checkbox" name="feature" data-id="{{ $feature->value }}">
                        <span class="ml-2 text-gray-700">{{ $feature->value }}</span>
                                                
                    @endif
                @endforeach
            </div>
    </div>

@endforeach
```

The issue is im not getting an error however if different products have the same attribute for example, two phones may have the colour `White` then the value appears twice in the filter, as shown below:
[image]

How could i adapt this so that the duplicate values only appears once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to create a list of all attributes after that simply apply

```
collect( $attributes )->unique()
```

This collection will give unique list of attributes further on unique attributes you could add a count for example xyz(3) and much more according to your logic.